# What is the solution of wave equation for a moving charge?

Tags: special-relativity, electromagnetic-radiation, electric-fields, reference-frames, maxwell-equations

The electric field of a point charge at rest in an inertial frame is static in the frame. Any location outside the charge follows the Maxwell equations in the vacuum, and as a consequence the wave equation. It is easy to see that both the Laplacian of the field and its time second derivative are zero. The wave equation is fulfilled trivially.

If this charge is moving with constant velocity in a lab, the electric (and magnetic) field are calculated by a Lorenz boost. In the lab's frame, the E-field is not linear with time for a given point, due to the Coulomb law, so the second derivative with respect to time is not zero. It seems that the wave equation is fulfilled not trivially by a function $f(\mathbf r, t)$.

If it fulfills the wave equation it is a EM wave, or not? If not, what is the form of this function?

Comment: A vanishing field satisfies the wave equation. A constant and uniform field field satisfies the wave equation. Are these waves?

Comment: Sounds like a vocabulary question. Is a wave a thing that oscillates? Or is it any solution to a wave equation? For physics, the second is the more useful concept. Most waves oscillate, but there are corner cases that do not. Or perhaps not so corner cases, such as an overdamped oscillator.

Comment: In the case of a moving charge, the second derivative is not zero. So it is not a trivial case. That is the source of my curiosity about the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Take the 4-vector potential as a differential 1-form with a time component only

$$A= 1/\sqrt{x^2+y^2 +z^2} \ dct$$
and perform a Lorentz boost

$$ x= x'\  \text{cosh}\ u + ct' \text{sinh}\ u, \quad  ct=ct'\ \text{cosh}\ u + x' \ \text{sinh}\ u ,\quad dct = dct' \ \text{cosh} \ u + dx' \ \text{sinh}\ u$$
with

$$\text{tanh} \ u =  \frac{v}{c}$$

The component factor of $A$ simply becomes moving as seen by a moving observer. But the differential is now a sum of a time component and and a x component, both growing exponentially with velocity $v\to c$.

$$x^2 \to ( x'\  \text{cosh}\ u + ct' \text{sinh}\ u)^2$$

$$A = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x(ct',x')^2 + y^2 + z^2 }}  \ \left( dct' \ \text{cosh} \ u + dx' \ \text{sinh}\ u \right)$$
The exterior derivative now yields the vaccum solution of the Maxwell equation with a moving and distorted  electric field, the $$dct'\wedge (dx',dy',dz') = E_{x',y',z'}$$ components,  and the $$(dx'\wedge dy', dy'\wedge dz', dz'\wedge dx')=B_{z',x',y'}$$ of a moving magnetic field, induced by the current of the moving point charge.

The fields automatically  solve the vacuum equations with a moving singularity of charge and current by the invariance of the Maxwell equations under this specific boost.

Answer (score 0):

The electric field, in the frame of a charge $q$, in a point $P = (x_0,y_0,z_0)$ is:
$$\mathbf E(x_0,y_0,z_0) = \frac{kq}{(x_0^2+y_0^2+z_0^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}(x_0,y_0,z_0)$$
In order to express the fields in the lab's frame, for which the charge is moving in the direction $x$ with velocity $v$, we make a Lorentz boost:
$$\mathbf E'(x_0,y_0,z_0) = \frac{kq}{(x_0^2+y_0^2+z_0^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}(x_0,\gamma y_0,\gamma z_0)$$
By the way, there was no magnetic field in the charge frame, but in the lab's frame:
$$\mathbf B'(x_0,y_0,z_0) = \frac{kq}{(x_0^2+y_0^2+z_0^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}(0,\gamma (\beta z_0,-\gamma \beta y_0)$$
where $$\beta = \frac{v}{c}......................\gamma = \frac{1}{1-\beta^2}$$

$P$ is still expressed in the charge coordinates. In order to change to lab's coordinates we make a inverse boost:
$x_0 = \gamma (x - vt)$, $y_0 = y$, $z_0 = z$.
Substituting in the expressions for the fields:
$$\mathbf E'(t,x,y,z) = \frac{kq\gamma}{(\gamma^2 (x - vt)^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}((x - vt),y,z)$$
$$\mathbf B'(t,x,y,z) = \frac{kq\gamma}{(\gamma^2 (x - vt)^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}(0,-\beta z,\beta y)$$
It is interesting to note that the direction of the electric field is radial with respect to the present location of the charge in the lab's frame. It can be checked that the fields are solutions for all the Maxwell equations. Let's verify only one of them:

$$ \nabla \cdot \mathbf E' = 0 \implies \frac{\partial E'_x}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial E'_y}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial E'_z}{\partial z} = 0 $$
$$\frac{\partial E'_x}{\partial x} = \frac{kq\gamma}{(\gamma^2 (x - vt)^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}} - \frac{3kq\gamma^3(x-vt)^2}{(\gamma^2 (x - vt)^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac{5}{2}}} $$
$$\frac{\partial E'_y}{\partial y} = \frac{kq\gamma}{(\gamma^2 (x - vt)^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}} - \frac{3kq\gamma y^2}{(\gamma^2 (x - vt)^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac{5}{2}}} $$
$$\frac{\partial E'_z}{\partial z} = \frac{kq\gamma}{(\gamma^2 (x - vt)^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}} - \frac{3kq\gamma z^2}{(\gamma^2 (x - vt)^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac{5}{2}}} $$
The sum is zero as can easily be checked.

As all the Maxwell equations without sources are fulfilled, and the wave equation is derived from them, it also must be fulfilled. But, let's check it for $E'_z$ anyway.

$$\frac{\partial^2 E'_z}{\partial t^2} = -\frac{3kqv^2\gamma^3 z}{(\gamma^2 (x - vt)^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac{5}{2}}} + \frac{15kqv^2\gamma^5 z(x - vt)^2}{(\gamma^2 (x - vt)^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac{7}{2}}}$$

$$\frac{\partial^2 E_z}{\partial x^2} = -\frac{3kq\gamma^3z}{(\gamma^2 (x - vt)^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac{5}{2}}} + \frac{15kq\gamma^5(x - vt)^2z}{(\gamma^2 (x - vt)^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac{7}{2}}}$$

$$\frac{\partial^2 E_z}{\partial y^2} = -\frac{3kq\gamma z }{(\gamma^2 (x - vt)^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac{5}{2}}}+\frac{15kq\gamma zy^2 }{(\gamma^2 (x - vt)^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac{7}{2}}}$$

$$\frac{\partial^2 E'_z}{\partial z^2} = -\frac{3kq\gamma z}{(\gamma^2 (x - vt)^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac{5}{2}}} - \frac{6kq\gamma z}{(\gamma^2 (x - vt)^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac{5}{2}}}+\frac{15kq\gamma z^3}{(\gamma^2 (x - vt)^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac{7}{2}}} $$

$$\nabla^2 E_z = \frac{-3kq\gamma^3 z}{(\gamma^2 (x - vt)^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac{5}{2}}} + \frac{-12kq\gamma z}{(\gamma^2 (x - vt)^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac{5}{2}}}+(\gamma^4 (x-vt)^2 + y^2 + z^2)\frac{15kq\gamma z}{(\gamma^2 (x - vt)^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac{7}{2}}}$$
$$\nabla^2 E_z = \frac{-3kq\gamma^3 z}{(\gamma^2 (x - vt)^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac{5}{2}}} + \frac{-12kq\gamma z}{(\gamma^2 (x - vt)^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac{5}{2}}}+(\gamma^4 (x-vt)^2 + \gamma^2 (x - vt)^2+ y^2 + z^2 - \gamma^2 (x - vt)^2)\frac{15kq\gamma z}{(\gamma^2 (x - vt)^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac{7}{2}}}$$

$$\nabla^2 E_z = \frac{-3kq\gamma^3 z}{(\gamma^2 (x - vt)^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac{5}{2}}}+\frac{-12kq\gamma z}{(\gamma^2 (x - vt)^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac{5}{2}}} +(\gamma^4-\gamma^2) (x-vt)^2\frac{15kq\gamma z}{(\gamma^2 (x - vt)^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac{7}{2}}} + \frac{15kq\gamma z}{(\gamma^2 (x - vt)^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac{5}{2}}}$$

$$\nabla^2 E_z = \frac{-3kq\gamma^3 z}{(\gamma^2 (x - vt)^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac{5}{2}}}+\frac{3kq\gamma z}{(\gamma^2 (x - vt)^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac{5}{2}}} +(\gamma^2-1) (x-vt)^2\frac{15kq\gamma^3 z}{(\gamma^2 (x - vt)^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac{7}{2}}} $$

$$\nabla^2 E_z = (1-\gamma^2)\frac{3kq\gamma z}{(\gamma^2 (x - vt)^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac{5}{2}}} +(\gamma^2-1) (x-vt)^2\frac{15kq\gamma^3 z}{(\gamma^2 (x - vt)^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac{7}{2}}}$$

But $$1 - \gamma^2 = -\beta^2\gamma^2 = -\frac{v^2\gamma^2}{c^2}$$

$$\nabla^2 E_z = \frac{-3kq\gamma^3 v^2 z}{c^2(\gamma^2 (x - vt)^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac{5}{2}}} +\frac{15kq\gamma^5 v^2 (x-vt)^2 z}{c^2(\gamma^2 (x - vt)^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac{7}{2}}} $$
And the conclusion:
$$\frac{\partial^2 E'_z}{\partial t^2} = c^2\nabla^2 E_z$$

So, while not being functions of the form $f(\mathbf {k\cdot r}-ct)$, (in another words: even not being a EM wave) the fields are solutions of the wave equation.